# session expire time in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter config.php file,we can set session expire time in seconds `$config['sess_expiration']       = 300;`.
Now I have two part for my web site,user part and admin part.I need user session expires after 10 minutes(600sec) and admin session expires after 5 minutes(300sec) .
Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to replace the current `CI_Session` instance within your admin with a new instance having those options passed in the `$params` array in the constructor.

The other variant would be that you extend the `CI_Session` class with your own variant which offers a method to change expiration time or can deal with a second config item which it's processes conditionally.